# Monitor MySQLdb in python for new entries and Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm looking for a way to constantly check my database (MySQL) for new entries. Once a new entry is committed I want to output it in a webpage using Flask.
Since the process takes time to finish I would like to give the users the impression it took only few seconds to retrieve data.

For now I'm waiting that the whole process finishes to give to the user the whole result. But I would prefer to update the result web-page every time a new entry was added to the DB. So for example the first entry is added to the DB, immediately the user can see it on the web-page, then a second entry is added the user can now see both the first and the second entries on the web-page and so on. I don't know if it has to come from flask or other ways

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can set MySQL to log all commits to General Query Log and monitor all changes (for example via [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) or [PyNotify](http://home.gna.org/py-notify/)). Once the file changes, you can parse the new log entries and get the signal. By this way you'll avoid pooling for changes.

The better way would be of course send the signal while storing data to the database.